# Populate a drop-down in Vue.js from an ajax call

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I want to be able to make an ajax call and to use the results returned to generate the options of a drop-down using [vue.js](/questions/tagged/vue.js). 
I can do this:

```
<select v-model="selected">
  <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.value">
    {{ option.text }}
  </option>
</select>
<span>Selected: {{ selected }}</span>
```

.js file

```
new Vue({
  el: '...',
  data: {
    selected: 'A',
    options: [
      { text: 'One', value: 'A' },
      { text: 'Two', value: 'B' },
      { text: 'Three', value: 'C' }
    ]
  }
})
```

But I don't want to have my options hard coded but instead to come from the ajax call.

Ajax call looks something like this:

```
function pullEmployees(){
        var eventOwnerId = $('#eventOwner').val();
        var eventOwnerName = $('#eventOwner :selected').text();
        $.ajax({
            url: "employees.cfm",
            data: {
                eventOwnerId: eventOwnerId,
                eventOwnerName: eventOwnerName,
                method : "updateOwners"
            },

            success: function(results) {
              // results will have a list of objects where each objects has     two properties (ID and Value)
            }
    });
}
```

I am really new in [vue.js](/questions/tagged/vue.js) and I would appreciate if someone can help.

Comment: So what's the problem so far? The only issue I see in your code at the moment is `this` will not be Vue in your `success` callback.

Comment: My problem is that I don't know how to attach the results of the ajax call to the options attribute of vue object. If you see in my above sample, I have hard-coded the options (text: 'One', value: 'A' , text: 'Two', value: 'B' etc..)

Comment: You said the objects come down as {id, value}. Do they need to be {text, value}?

Comment: Actually that was a typo, they come as {ID, text}. By the way do I have to tell to the vue instance somehow that which is my id and which is my text or the line "this.vue.data.options = results;" is gonna know how to render the drop-down itself?

Comment: Where is pullEmployees located? Is it a vue method or a function outside Vue? What exactly is `results`? Just an array of option objects?

Comment: yes pullEmployees is outside Vue. I don't how can that be put inside Vue. Now is located on a .js file. results is just an array of option JSON object.Two properties only, ID and Text

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149167/discussion-between-bert-evans-and-doarna).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the example below, I am simulating your ajax call with a `setTimeout`. Basically you want to capture the result of `new Vue()` in a variable and then set the `options` property of that Vue with the results of your ajax call.

I also updated your template to reflect that the options you are returning have the structure `{ID, text}`.

```js
console.clear()

let app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selected: 'A',
    options: []
  }
})


function pullEmployees(){
  let options = [
    { text: 'One', ID: 'A' },
    { text: 'Two', ID: 'B' },
    { text: 'Three', ID: 'C' }
  ];
  setTimeout(() => app.options = options, 1000)
}
pullEmployees()
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selected">
    <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.ID">
      {{ option.text }}
    </option>
  </select>
  <span>Selected: {{ selected }}</span>
</div>
```

However all of this can be done inside Vue. It doesn't need to be done outside.

```
let app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selected: 'A',
    options: []
  },
  methods:{
    pullEmployees(){
      var eventOwnerId = $('#eventOwner').val();
      var eventOwnerName = $('#eventOwner :selected').text();
      $.ajax({
        url: "employees.cfm",
        data: {
          eventOwnerId: eventOwnerId,
          eventOwnerName: eventOwnerName,
          method : "updateOwners"
        },
        success: results => this.options = results
      });
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    this.pullEmployees()
  }
})
```

If `eventOwner` is part of the Vue as well you could just get that value as a data property from Vue.

Comment: Can you give me an example how to put eventOwner inside Vue. You can see from my code how I am reading those values now from the DOM. 
Also "el:#app" does that mean that the ID of the select is "app"?

Comment: @DoArNa I built this [codepen](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/OgdrpN) while I was playing with your code. It shows how you would do that. It throws an error when making the ajax call, because obviously I dont have access to your server. Also, you might want get the options when the owner changes instead of in `mounted`.

Comment: I really appreciate the time you are taking to help me on this. From what I understand when the page loads it will load the drop-down with Mary and Bob however what I want is when page load the drop-down has the the options that came from the ajax call. I understand that you want be able to have a working model because you can't access the server but at least how the code would be written? There is no conditions on the page that can change the list options later after the page is loaded so I don't need to worry about updating the select element anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Store your vue instance as a variable:

```
var vue = new Vue(// stuff...);
```

and then for the Ajax be careful about the scope of `this`:

```
function pullEmployees(){
        var _this = this; // bind "this" to local var
        var eventOwnerId = $('#eventOwner').val();
        var eventOwnerName = $('#eventOwner :selected').text();
        $.ajax({
            url: "employees.cfm",
            data: {
                eventOwnerId: eventOwnerId,
                eventOwnerName: eventOwnerName,
                method : "updateOwners"
            },

            success: function(results) {
              _this.vue.data.options = results; // set data
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: On my vue instance do I start the options attribute as empty string? ( data: {
    options: = ""}

Comment: You should probably initialize it as an empty array.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try in a minute.